# I am trying to convert a sql code in to pandas script and am getting the following error:

Tags: python, sql, pandas

My query is as follows :

```
"UPDATE " & tblMaster & " SET Reason_Code='" & strReason & "', Failure_Status='Failed', Failure_date'" & strUDate & "' WHERE Name='" & strName & "' AND date>'" & strUDate & "' AND date<'" & strLDate & "'"
```

The query will update and fill Reason_Code, Failure_Date and Failure_Status columns for each event

trying to convert the above query into python pandas.
 here is the code i have tried:

```
Master11.loc[(Master11.Name == failure.Name ) & (Master11.Date > failure.Failure_Date) & (Master11.Date < failure.Install_Date), 'Reason_Code'] = failure.Reason_Code
Master11.loc[(Master11.Name == failure.Name ) & (Master11.Date > failure.Failure_Date) & (Master11.Date < failure.Install_Date), 'Failure_Status'] = 'Failed'
Master11.loc[(Master11.Name == failure.Name ) & (Master11.Date > failure.Failure_Date) & (Master11.Date < failure.Install_Date), 'Failure_Status'] = failure.Failure_Date
```

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Sample input:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUSkW.png)

sample output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxv9r.png)

Comment: can you show us a sample input (just a few rows) and your expected output?

Comment: can you add it to your question? have a look at MVCE for SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: where is `failure.name`, also please post raw output of your file either in code or as something we can copy and paste into our own IDE to come up with a solution.